# Register internal ionic app path as REST provider

Tags: json, angular, rest, ionic2

For certain reasons I'd like to build an in-app like REST endpoint in my ionic 3 app. Then frontend components should be able to call data from the in-app backend by simple http.request. I.E. like so:

```
this.http.request("/#/api/local/getUsers", requestOptions).subscribe(
      (rc) => { console.log(rc.text()); },
      (err) => { console.log(err) }
    );
```

The result of this request should be a json list of valid users (whatever, determined by the registered controller and request parameters).

I have succeeded to register the path for a component like so:

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'api',
  segment: 'local/:method',
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-fgttm',
  templateUrl: 'fgttm.html',
})
export class FgttmPage ...
```

And when I navigate to /#/api/local/getUsers I can see the (unfortunately HTML) output like written in fgttm.html.
But the `this.http.request("/#/api/local/getUsers"` just recieves the plain index.html template (far away from json but at least a 200).

What am I missing here? Is there a way to bind an ionic-provider to a path (like a controller in angular or drupal)?

EDIT: I have also tried to use ionic-native/deeplinks. Doesn't work. My deeplink routes get called when I click on a link in the device browser like expected. But the routes do not get called when I try to access them via the `http.request(myscheme://myurl.com/api` etc. from inside the app.

EDIT2: Using an in-app light-httpd server (`ionic-native/httpd`) is also not an option because testing in Chrome wouldn't be possible.